# mvvmcross videoview URL binding

Tags: android, xamarin, cross-platform, mvvmcross

I am new in MVVMCross and currently struggling with a binding issue.
Trying to bind the URL of an video with the VideoView component in android.

- Is there any Mvx.MvxBind tag that can do it automatically?
- Otherwise, how can i pass the URL from the MvxViewModel to the MvxActivity?

If the first option is not possible i will try to get the URL and play the video as explained here: http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/video/play_video/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MvvmCross is very flexible. What you're asking for is not something that is built-in, but you can easily extend MvvmCross to add support for it.

MvvmCross has what are called Binding Builders. This is where you register custom Target Bindings. A binding takes a type, like *VideoView*, and a property name like "*VideoUri"*.

When MvvmCross sees a binding attribute like: `local:MvxBind="VideoUri MyVideoUri"` it will take the property value from *MyVideoUri*, then call the custom binding, which ulimiately will call `videoView.SetVideoURI()`.

Here are the steps you need to take.

1) In your Android project, edit *Setup.cs* and add the following, to register your custom binding builder.

```
    protected override MvxAndroidBindingBuilder CreateBindingBuilder()
    {
        return new MyAndroidBindingBuilder();
    }
```

2) Create a custom binding builder that subclasses the default Android binding builder:

```
public class MyAndroidBindingBuilder : MvxAndroidBindingBuilder
{
    protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        base.FillTargetFactories(registry);

        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<VideoView>("VideoUri",
                                             videoView => new MvxVideoViewUriTargetBinding(videoView));

    }
}
```

3) Create a custom target binding for type VideoView and property "VideoUri":

```
public class MvxVideoViewUriTargetBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
{
    public MvxVideoViewUriTargetBinding(object target) : base(target)
    {
    }

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof (string); }
    }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        var videoView = (VideoView) target;
        videoView.SetVideoURI(Uri.Parse((string)value));
    }
}
```

To use it in your layout, simply create the following:

1) In your *layout.xml*

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/SampleVideoView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    local:MvxBind="VideoUri MyVideoUri" />
```

2) In your *ViewModel*, add a property for MyVidoeUri

```
    public string MyVideoUri
    {
        get { return "http://ia600507.us.archive.org/25/items/Cartoontheater1930sAnd1950s1/PigsInAPolka1943.mp4"; }
    }
```

3) In you *View*, you can start the video like this:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyLayout);

        // SetVideoURI() already called via binding
        var videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.SampleVideoView);
        videoView.Start();
     }
```

Look at the source for MvxAndroidBindingBuilder to see the current bindings. 
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/bbf9a2ac76e74d9404f4b57036c6e29dfe2cc6c3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.cs

Hope this helps.