# How to bind to the title of a UISegmentedControl segment with MVVMCross?

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

Is it possible to bind a property of a view model to the title of a segment in UISegmentedControl?

I'm aware of the SetTitle() method, but not sure if it's possible to bind to this in MvvmCross.

Comment: Here's my answer to a similar question. Just change references from Android to Touch, VideoView to UISegmentedControl, and change property name from VideoUri to Title:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132621/mvvmcross-videoview-url-binding/27137091#27137091

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to post my own answer to this but it's based entirely on your other answer with the relevant changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of [Kiliman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132621/mvvmcross-videoview-url-binding/27137091#27137091) to a similar question.

Follow the first 2 steps from that answer. Then create the following custom binding builder.

```
public class MyTouchBindingBuilder : MvxTouchBindingBuilder
{
    protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        base.FillTargetFactories (registry);

        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<UISegmentedControl> ("Title", segmentTitle => new MvxSegmentTitleTargetBinding (segmentTitle));
    }
}
```

And the following custom target binding.

```
public class MvxSegmentTitleTargetBinding : MvxConvertingTargetBinding
{
    public MvxSegmentTitleTargetBinding(object target) : base(target)
    {

    }

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get {return typeof(MyViewModel);}
    }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        var segmentControl = (UISegmentedControl)target;
        MyViewModel myViewModel = (MyViewModel)value;

        segmentControl.SetTitle(myViewModel.MyFirstValue, 0);
        segmentControl.SetTitle(myViewModel.MySecondValue, 1);
    }
}
```

And use it in your view like so.

```
set.Bind (MySegmentControl).For ("Title").To ((MyViewModel vm) => vm);
```