# Proper way of handling image caching e.g. Picasso with MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using a RecyclerView and the Recycler items are databound using MvvmCross. Each databound object contains imageurl which I am trying to load using the [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) image library. My first idea was to to call Picasso within a ValueConverter. To use Picasso I need the context object and I am not sure if it is possible to pass the databound ImageView as a parameter to the converter. Here is the code...

```
public class MyImageConverter : IMvxValueConverter
{
    protected override object Convert(object value, object parameter)
    {       
        var imageUrl = (string)value;
        // How to optain context or direct access to imageView?
        var imageView = new ImageView(context);
        Picasso.With(context).Load(imageUrl).Into(imageView);
        var bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.Drawable).Bitmap;
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

And the axml fragment

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/myImageView"
app:MvxBind="Bitmap MyImageConverter(ImageUrl)" />
```

It would probably be best to handle the Picasso loading async but I would still need to access the item ImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom target binding.

See for example: [mvvmcross videoview URL binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132621/mvvmcross-videoview-url-binding/27137091#27137091)

Things have been moved around since I wrote the last answer, so here's the link to the current Android bindings.

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/MvvmCross/Binding/Droid/MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.cs